# Create element thats embraces an existing one

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I need to create a div that will contain another div that already exists in DOM.

`<div class='a'></div>` to `<div class='b'><div class='a'></div></div>`

I created a code to do that, but it detach the existing element and attach it on the new one, so its sequence on the parent element will change, it will be added on the end of the parent. I think this can be a problem in the future, e.g if the structure is managed with floats, perhaps?

So my code is:

```
var obj = $('#existingDiv');
var p = obj.parent();
var d = obj.detach();
var n = p.append('<div id="newDiv"></div>');
$("#newdiv").append(d);
```

*Another problem on this code is that I have to create a reference to the new div (`id="newDiv"`) or whatelse to use it later. It will be nicer if the function doens't need that to reference the new element, just use another automatic way, but this is not the real problem.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$("#existingDiv").wrap("<div id='newDiv'></div>");
```

This method will insert the new wrapper element at the exact position the existing element was, and does not require building a jQuery object around the wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.wrap()` like this -

```
$('div.a').wrap("<div class='b'></div>");
```

Comment: Thank you man, your answer is right but I marked Frédéric because he answered first.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the second problem in your code (creating a reference to newly created elements) can be done with the `.on()` method. If you have a similar naming convention for all new elements (IE, ID's all start with "new"), this handler should work (for clicking, change to what you need):

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="new"]', function() {
    //do stuff here
    var currentID = $(this).attr("id"); // <--Grabs ID of clicked element
});
```

API Ref: http://api.jquery.com/on/